# Replacing missing values coded by "." in an R dataframe

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe with missing values coded by ".", and I want to recode the values as NA:

`df <- data.frame("h"=c(1,1,"."))`

I try the following:

`df$h[df$h == "."] <- NA`

But the `NA` appears as a `<NA>`, and I can't execute commands like `mean(df$h,rm.na=TRUE)`

Does anyone know what the problem is? When I recode numbers as NA there's no problem

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I think you meant `na.rm = TRUE`, not `rm.na = TRUE`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `is.na` function. No need to convert to factor, although the fact that you had character values did cause coercion of what you wanted to be numeric.

```
> df <- data.frame("h"=c(1,1,"."))
> is.na(df) <- df=="."
> df
     h
1    1
2    1
3 <NA>
```

I'm not sure why @TylerRinker deleted his response regarding using 'na.strings', since I thought it to be the correct answer.

Comment: Looking at this a year later I realized that a) the OP misunderstood how missing values were displayed when they are in factors or character vectors, and b) that the main problem was not an error in recoding to an R-missing-value, which the OP's code already correctly had done correctly, but was rather the misspelling error that @joran identified.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your column df$h is a factor. Try to make it a character first and then replace the "."-values:

```
df$h <- as.character(df$h)
df$h[df$h == "."] <- NA
```

Here you see the result:

```
df[is.na(df$h),]
```

Of course once you got rid of the dots you can convert it to a numeric variable to calculate with it if you want:

```
df$h <- as.numeric(df$h)
```

Comment: Actually, the fact that the column is a factor doesn't make a difference.  You can still match values that equal `"."`.  The real problem, as you noted, is that you need to convert to numeric before calculating the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right, it is a factor. first convert it into numeric by the below syntax

```
df <- transform(df, h=as.numeric(h))
```

and replace missing with zero

```
df$h[is.na(df$h)] <- "0" and then view the data View(df)
```