# parsing quotes out of "NA" strings

Tags: r, sqldf

My dataframe has some variables that contain missing values as strings like `"NA"`. What is the most efficient way to parse all columns in a dataframe that contain these and convert them into real NAs that are catched by functions like `is.na()`?

I am using sqldf to query the database.

Reproducible example:

```
vect1 <- c("NA", "NA", "BANANA", "HELLO")
vect2 <- c("NA", 1, 5, "NA")
vect3 <- c(NA, NA, "NA", "NA")


df = data.frame(vect1,vect2,vect3)
```

Comment: The best way would be to deal with these when you are reading in the data. If you are reading in with the standard tools have a look at the `na.strings` argument. Otherwise [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351089/replacing-missing-values-coded-by-in-an-r-dataframe) should help, but replace the period with NA

Comment: what are considered the standard tools? I'm reading all data from a sql database which might make it hard to deal with these when reading the data

Comment: okay, what function are you using specifically.. pretty sure they will have an na.strings argument

Comment: yes I don't think na.strings would work in my situation unfortunately

Comment: I am using sqldf to query the database

Comment: .hmmm, not so sure then. But the link in the comment should help  to do this after reading in

Comment: thank you for adding that in. I can't seem to find an na.strings equivalent for sqldf. What's so wrong about parsing it after reading the data though?

Comment: For me, mainly it is just easier. But (i think) when you make these replacements that copies of the data are made which can be a problem for large data.

Comment: I agree, I could write a for loop that went through all rows and converted all "NA" strings to real NAs but that would take very long since my dataframe is about 5 million rows and about 250 variables, hence the "most efficient" in my question

Comment: Building on @user20650's suggestion, you can also use `type.convert` after having read the data in, as I did [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34567882/1270695).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to the alternatives, you can also use `replace` instead of the typical `blah[index] <- NA` approach. `replace` would look like:

```
df <- replace(df, df == "NA", NA)
```

---

Another alternative to consider is `type.convert`. This is the function that R uses when reading data in to automatically convert column types. Thus, the result is different from your current approach in that, for instance, the second column gets converted to numeric.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), na.strings = "NA"))
df
```

---

Here's a performance comparison. The sample data is from @roland's answer.

Here are the functions to test:

```
funop <- function() {
  df[df == "NA"] <- NA
  df
}

funr <- function() {
  ind <- which(vapply(df, function(x) class(x) %in% c("character", "factor"), FUN.VALUE = TRUE))
  as.data.table(df)[, names(df)[ind] := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    is.na(x) <- x == "NA"
    x
  }), .SDcols = ind][]
}

funam1 <- function() replace(df, df == "NA", NA)

funam2 <- function() {
  df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), na.strings = "NA"))
  df
}
```

Here's the benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funop(), funr(), funam1(), funam2(), times = 10)
# Unit: seconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   funop() 3.629832 3.750853 3.909333 3.855636 4.098086 4.248287    10
#    funr() 3.074825 3.212499 3.320430 3.279268 3.332304 3.685837    10
#  funam1() 3.714561 3.899456 4.238785 4.065496 4.280626 5.512706    10
#  funam2() 1.391315 1.455366 1.623267 1.566486 1.606694 2.253258    10
```

`replace` would be the same as @roland's approach, which is the same as @jgozal's. However, the `type.convert` approach would result in different column types.

```
all.equal(funop(), setDF(funr()))
all.equal(funop(), funam())

str(funop())
# 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ vect1: Factor w/ 3 levels "BANANA","HELLO",..: 2 2 NA 2 1 1 1 NA 1 1 ...
#  $ vect2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","5","NA": NA 2 1 NA 1 NA NA 1 NA 2 ...
#  $ vect3: Factor w/ 1 level "NA": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

str(funam2())
# 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ vect1: Factor w/ 2 levels "BANANA","HELLO": 2 2 NA 2 1 1 1 NA 1 1 ...
#  $ vect2: int  NA 5 1 NA 1 NA NA 1 NA 5 ...
#  $ vect3: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this nice way of doing it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503266/r-replace-all-particular-values-in-a-data-frame) question:

So for this particular situation it would just be:

```
df[df=="NA"]<-NA
```

It only took about 30 seconds with 5 million rows and ~250 variables

Comment: You can do this much faster, e.g., using package data.table. But you don't provide a reproducible example of `df`, which precludes me from composing and testing/benchmarking an answer.

Comment: reproducible example added

Answer (score 4):

This is slightly faster:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- do.call(data.frame, lapply(df, sample, size = 1e7, replace = TRUE))
df2 <- df
system.time(df[df=="NA"]<-NA )
# user      system     elapsed 
#3.601       0.378       3.984 

library(data.table)
setDT(df2)
system.time({
  #find character and factor columns
  ind <- which(vapply(df2, function(x) class(x) %in% c("character", "factor"), FUN.VALUE = TRUE))
  #assign by reference
  df2[, names(df2)[ind] := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  is.na(x) <- x == "NA"
  x
}), .SDcols = ind]
})
# user      system     elapsed 
#2.484       0.190       2.676 
all.equal(df, setDF(df2))
#[1] TRUE
```